# Fail SSIS "Execute Process Task" if false is returned

Tags: ssis, powershell, ssis-2012

I have an "Execute Process Task" that calls Powershell and checks if a folder is empty. I'm wanting the SSIS job to fail if $false is returned.

Here is the code

```
param ([string] $FolderLocation)

$FolderLocation = 'C:\Temp\IsFolderEmpty\'

if( (Get-ChildItem $FolderLocation | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
{
    #Folder Empty
    return $true

} Else {

    return $false

}
```

Any time I run this in SSIS, it always runs whether `$true` or `$false` is returned. I've tried creating a new variable and using it in the `StandardOutputVariable` but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Which problem would you rather solve: how to check if a folder is empty or how do I get a true/false returned from this execute package task?

Comment: I'd like to check if a folder is empty in SSIS and if it isn't, fail the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Script Task to check the value of the SSIS variable that is set as the `StandardOutputVariable` of the Execute Process Task.  If this value is false the `Dts.Events.FireError` method raises an error event that can be used to fail the package.  The code below is an example of this using C#, where an error is raised when the variable is `false`.  The SSIS variable will need to be set in the `ReadOnlyVariables` field of the Script Task to allow it to be accessed.

```
    if (!Convert.ToBoolean(Dts.Variables["User::YourVariable"].Value))
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Error", "Error Raised from Folder Check", null, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Doing this in C# makes more sense. This got me over the hump